# Как сериалиазовать Xml вне зависимости от типа данных

Tags: c#

Есть класс для сериализации и десериализации

```
 public static void SerializeObject(this List<Object> list,string fileName)
        {
            var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<Object>));
            using (var stream = File.OpenWrite(fileName))
            {
                serializer.Serialize(stream, list);
            }
        }

        public static void Deserialize(this List<Object> list, string fileName)
        {
            var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<Object>));
            using (var stream = File.OpenRead(fileName))
            {
                var other = (List<Object>)(serializer.Deserialize(stream));
                list.Clear();
                list.AddRange(other);
            }
        }
```

У меня также есть класс `User`

```
public class User 
{
  public string Name {get;set;}
}
```

Таких классов много и я хочу сделать метод (де)сериализации универсальным. Как это сделать? Чтобы на вход поступал `List<T>` а он сам его в нужный формат конвертировал

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам помогут [обобщения](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/) (генерики - generics).

```
    public static void SerializeObject<T>(this List<T> list, string fileName)
    {
        var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<T>));
        using (var stream = File.OpenWrite(fileName))
        {
            serializer.Serialize(stream, list);
        }
    }

    public static void Deserialize<T>(this List<T> list, string fileName)
    {
        var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<T>));
        using (var stream = File.OpenRead(fileName))
        {
            var other = (List<T>)(serializer.Deserialize(stream));
            list.Clear();
            list.AddRange(other);
        }
    }
```

---

Если файл существует, то метод `OpenWrite` открывает его, не очищая. И если в нём было данных больше, чем будет записано в ходе сериализации, то в конце файла окажется мусор (как произошло у меня в ходе тестирования). Поэтому следует заменить этот метод на `Create`.

Вы назвали первый метод `SerializeObject`, а второй `Deserialize`. Желательно или обоим приписать `Object`, или у обоих удалить.

Comment: Только есть 1 минус - это подойдет не для всех случаев. Например `items.Select(x=>new Foo()).Cast<object>().ToList().SerializeObject(...)` уронит метод\

Comment: @tym32167 - Это да. По-хорошему, метод `Deserialize` должен возвращать десериализованный объект и не быть методом расширения.

Comment: да не, пусть будет методом расширения сколько хочет :) Я про то, что обобщенный параметр не всегда соответствует типу передаваемого объекта, он может быть, к примеру, его базовым типом.

Comment: и, да, зачем затачивать метод под `List<T>`? Почему бы просто не сериализовать все подряд, типа `SerializeObject<T>(this T obj, string fileName)`